# Intercommunicators in MPI

Tags: mpi

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#define NUM_SPAWNS 2
// Based on the example from: http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Comm_spawn.html
void MPI_messenger(int stuff, int dest)
{
    MPI_Send(&stuff, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1,intercomm);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int my_rank;
    int size;
    int np = NUM_SPAWNS;
    int errcodes[NUM_SPAWNS];
    MPI_Comm parentcomm, intercomm, testcomm;
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Status stat;
    MPI_Comm_get_parent( &parentcomm );
    if (parentcomm == MPI_COMM_NULL)
    {
        MPI_Comm_spawn( "spawn_example4", MPI_ARGV_NULL, np, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, errcodes );
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
        int lol = 10;
        MPI_messenger(lol,0);
        MPI_messenger(lol,1);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
        int lol;
        MPI_Recv(&lol, 1, MPI_INT,0,1,parentcomm, &stat);


        std::cout << lol << "\n";
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Of course the intercommunicator intercomm is not defined in the scope of the function MPI_messenger. I wanted to know if and how I can get this intercommunicator inside the function without passing it as an argument.

Comment: You would better pass it as argument for the sake of being future proof. Newer MPI standards will most likely incorporate the "MPI endpoints" feature that would allow several MPI processes to run as threads inside a single OS process and global variables do not play nice with multithreading.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will go with this approach, it was the one I was considering to begin with. I was just wandering if there was any function in MPI which would allow you to get the intercommunicators linked to a group, such as **MPI_Get_parent()** to get the communicator to the parent process. It would be nice to have something such as MPI_Get_childgroups() which would give you an array of communicators and their size.

Comment: I am not aware of any functionality in MPI 2.2 that allows you to enumerate the existing groups and communicator handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would any other variable: declare it globally, or in some other common scope visible to both `main()` and `MPI_messenger()` (e.g. within the same class as a member).